# Apply a function with multiple parameters in input in groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to substitute the NaN and NaT values of the Value1 column, with others calculated with a function that takes in input Value2 and Value3 (if they exist) of the same row of Value1. This is done for each ID. To do this, I would use 'groupby' and then 'apply'.But I get an error: *'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed*. Could you help me? Thanks in advance!

```
ID1 = [2002070, 2002070, 2002740,2002740,2003010]
ID2 = [2002070, 200800, 200800,2002740,2002740]
ID3 = [2002740, 2002740, 2002070, 2002070,2003010]
Value1 = [4.5, 4.2, 3.7, 4.8, 4.4]
Value2 = [7.2, 6.4, 10, 2.3, 1.5]
Value3 = [8.4, 8.4, 8.4, 7.4, 7.4]
date1 = ['2008-05-14', '2005-12-07','2008-10-27', '2009-04-20', '2012-03-01']
date2 = ['2005-12-07','2003-10-10', '2004-05-14', '2011-06-03', '2015-07-05']
date3 = ['2010-10-22', '2012-03-01', '2013-11-28', '2005-12-07', '2012-03-01']
date1=pd.to_datetime(date1)
date2=pd.to_datetime(date2)
date3=pd.to_datetime(date3)
df1=pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID1, 'Value1': Value1, 'Date1':date1}).sort_values('Date1')
df2=pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID2, 'Value2': Value2, 'Date2':date2}).sort_values('Date2')
df3=pd.DataFrame({'ID': ID3, 'Value3': Value3, 'Date3':date3}).sort_values('Date3')
ok = df1.merge(df2, left_on=['ID','Date1'],right_on=['ID','Date2'], how='outer', sort=True)
ok1 = ok.merge(df3, left_on='ID',right_on='ID', how='inner', sort=True )
```

the df I obtain is this:

```
      ID   Value1  Date1   Value2  Date2    Value3  Date3
0   2002070 4.2 2005-12-07  7.2 2005-12-07  7.4 2005-12-07
1   2002070 4.2 2005-12-07  7.2 2005-12-07  8.4 2013-11-28
2   2002070 4.5 2008-05-14  NaN     NaT     7.4 2005-12-07
3   2002070 4.5 2008-05-14  NaN     NaT     8.4 2013-11-28
4   2002740 3.7 2008-10-27  NaN     NaT     8.4 2010-10-22
5   2002740 3.7 2008-10-27  NaN     NaT     8.4 2012-03-01
6   2002740 4.8 2009-04-20  NaN     NaT     8.4 2010-10-22
7   2002740 4.8 2009-04-20  NaN     NaT     8.4 2012-03-01
8   2002740 NaN    NaT      2.3 2011-06-03  8.4 2010-10-22
9   2002740 NaN    NaT      2.3 2011-06-03  8.4 2012-03-01
10  2002740 NaN    NaT      1.5 2015-07-05  8.4 2010-10-22
11  2002740 NaN    NaT      1.5 2015-07-05  8.4 2012-03-01
12  2003010 4.4 2012-03-01  NaN     NaT     7.4 2012-03-01
```

this is the function I made:

```
def func(Value2, Value3):
    return Value2/((Value3/100)**2)
result = ok1.groupby("ID").Value1.apply(func(ok1.Value2, ok1.Value3))
```

Do you know how to apply this function only to a NaN Value1?  And how to put the NaT Date1 equal to Date2?

Comment: 1. I am trying your code and getting an error **"Series objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"**. Can you be more clear on what you are trying to do with Value1? Are you trying to overwrite the original value?

Comment: 2. You can replace a column NA with another column by using `df['Date1'].fillna(df['Date2'])`

Comment: 1. Yes I would like to overwrite the Nan value     2. yes, i was looking for this solution, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `func` is another `Series`, and pandas is not sure what you want to do with it - what would it mean to `apply` this series to the groups?

Is it that you want the values of this series to be assigned wherever there is a missing `Value1` in the original `DataFrame`?

In that case

```py
imputes = ok1.Value2.div(ok1.Value3.div(100).pow(2))  # same as your function

# overwrite missing values with the corresponding imputed values
ok1.Value1.fillna(imputes, inplace=True)

# overwrite missing dates with dates from another column
ok1.Date1.fillna(ok1.Date2, inplace=True)
```

However, it's not clear to me that this is quite what you wanted, given the presence of the `groupby`.

Comment: you are right, groupby wasn't the best choice, considering that I would substitute the value with others of the same row, so the info about the ID isn't relevant. You catched the problem perfectly, it is the best solution for me. Thank you